# How to prevent memory leaks from gms.Task?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-tasks-api

I use tasks in viewModel and want to remove listeners in onCleared but there is no method to do that, is it needed or not?
I have found onCompleteListener with activity paramenter that in result clears listener in onStop but i'd like to leave authentication logic in VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not needed. It should be garbage collected after the Task itself completes and becomes garbage collected.

Comment: What about temporary leaks? if there's a long fetching process and user navigates to another activity/fragment there would be a strong reference from listener to outer class(VM)

Comment: If that's how you implemented the listener, yes.  You will have to handle that case correctly on your own (by not using inner classes whose outer class is long-lived).